# Having problems with line 16 & 21 in C. What is (word[25], ! = '9')? Here's my code:

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h> 


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    char word[25];

    do 
        {
        printf("Enter a word:");
        scanf("%24 s", &word); }

    while
        (word[25], ! = '9');
    { 
        printf("%s starts with the letter %c\n", word, word[25]);
    }
    while
        (word[25], ! = '9');

    return(0);
```

Comment: `word[25], ! = '9'` is a wrong syntax. Post the real code.

Comment: Also `  &word  ` is wrong, either have `  word  ` or `  &word [0]  `.

Comment: word[25], will compile, but produce no output, simply careless use of the comma operator ( please look up ).

Comment: Declaring `  char word[25]  ` the string's first character is `  word[0]  ` and the last is `  word[24]  ` , `  word[25] is just the next memory location, and causes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `scanf("%24 s"` causes undefined behaviour (space is not a valid format specifier) , although that's the least of your problems

Comment: Thanx guys. I know I have to figure out the correct expression for: (word[0] ! = 9);

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `(word[25], ! = '9');` is simply a syntax error. The comma operator has to be followed by an expression, and `! = '9'` is not a valid expression.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char word[25];

    do 
        {
        printf("Enter a word:");
        scanf("%24 s", &word); }

    while
        (word[25] != '9');
    { 
        printf("%s starts with the letter %c\n", word, word[25]);
    }
    while
        (word[25] != '9');

    return(0);
```

Comment: You have a comma between word[25] and !=